# Dismiss Keyboard over a map conflicts with didTapCoordinate event

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitapgesturerecognizer

What should i do to remove conflicts between the tap gesture to dismiss the keyboard and other tap gestures related to the map ?

I have a TextField and a GMSMapView when the Keyboard is opened I can't dismiss it by clicking anywhere over the map 
also,I noticed that didTapCoordinate event is fired

Comment: for the desmiss keyboard simply use self.view.endEditing = YES

Answer (score 1):

Just add this property when keyboard is opened

```
yourtapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false;
```

This will disable tap gesture on views.